# Android custom backcground Drawable

Tags: android, customview, drawable

Есть дизайн макет `View` следующего типа:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Без проблем реализовал его в iOS, но в Android столкнулся с полным непониманием того, как приступить. Большинство ссылок предлагают реализовать кастомные изображения при помощи ресурсов, сам я ранее создавал простейшие background'ы при помощи переопределения `onDraw`.

Мне не нужен код, который реализовал бы такое(т.к очень хочется разобраться самому), но мне нужен совет, какой путь мне лучше выбрать - xml drawable / onDraw, использовать ли стандартные шейпы или прибегнуть к 9pathdrawable и т.д. Очень буду признателен за грамотный туториал (большинство туториалов описывают элементарные фигуры типа *RoundedRect* или *Oval*, что не помогает двигаться дальше). Всё осложняет полное отсутствие опыта в терминах дизайна - даже переводя названия некоторых свойств в xml или класса Canvas, я порой чувствую себя неуверенно, так как понимаю, что значить это может что угодно (например я до сих пор не могу понять, что такое dither).

Посему прошу дать мне толчок в нужном направлении.

## UPDATED 1:

9.png вещь интересная, но если выделять по однному региону по горизонтали и вертикали, все скейлится не очень грамотно (или я не правильно выбираю регионы?), а если регионов делать несколько, то компилятор выдает ошибку (nuff said)

```
AAPT: ERROR: 9-patch image /Users/iam/Desktop/LavkaLavka/res/drawable/tagbg.9.png malformed.
AAPT: Can't have more than one marked region along edge.
AAPT: Found at pixel #14 along bottom edge. :mergeDebugResources FAILED
```

Comment: а почему нельзя воспользоваться 9png ?

Comment: это видно даже по прикремленной картинке - view динамичное, подстраивающееся под длину надписи, а png штука очень статичная

Comment: @iamthevoid, вы ошибаетесь насчет статичности png в Android. Погуглите по `android nine-patch`

Comment: @iamthevoid, я же говорю вам не про PNG, а про 9PNG (NINE-PNG). Она как раз и создана для динамических объектов.

Comment: вариант интересный. но проблема с растягиванием по вертикали - если делать одну область - view деформируется, если больше - ругается компиляьор

AAPT: ERROR: 9-patch image /Users/iam/Desktop/LavkaLavka/res/drawable/tagbg.9.png malformed.
AAPT:        Can't have more than one marked region along edge.
AAPT:        Found at pixel #14 along bottom edge.
:mergeDebugResources FAILED

Comment: @iamthevoid, видимо вы не правильно установили поля в 9-patch. Обычно никаких проблем с растягиванием нет, просто выделяете 2 зоны - ту которая будет содержать данные  и ту которая будет масштабироваться.